# Error on iPod touch with phoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, ipod-touch

I got following error in console:

```
  "Error in success callback: com.phonegap.file9 = TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function."
```

My app works perfect on iPad and Android,but if fails to write files on iPod touch. Anybody know if this is a hardware issue or PhoneGap?